# why Jruby can't require 'net/http/server' and gnu.io.PortInUseException error

Tags: java, ruby, error-handling, load, jruby

I'm trying to run jruby application, 
but it fails with error:

```
LoadError: no such file to load -- net/http/server
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1054
  require at ../jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36
   (root) at lib/main.rb:4
```

What does it means? o_O

Some times, I see another error:

```
bmalets:trunk bmalets$ sh bin/qatcher.sh 
Experimental:  JNI_OnLoad called.
Stable Library
=========================================
Native lib Version = RXTX-2.1-7
Java lib Version   = RXTX-2.1-7
Connecting to serial port /dev/tty.usbmodemfa131
CommPortIdentifier.java:354:in `open': gnu.io.PortInUseException: Unknown Application
    from NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2:in `invoke0'
    from NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39:in `invoke'
    from DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25:in `invoke'
    from Method.java:597:in `invoke'
    from JavaMethod.java:470:in `invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling'
    from JavaMethod.java:328:in `invokeDirect'
    from InstanceMethodInvoker.java:71:in `call'
    from CachingCallSite.java:346:in `cacheAndCall'
    from CachingCallSite.java:204:in `call'
    from CallTwoArgNode.java:59:in `interpret'
    from InstAsgnNode.java:95:in `interpret'
    from NewlineNode.java:105:in `interpret'
    from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
    from ASTInterpreter.java:74:in `INTERPRET_METHOD'
    from InterpretedMethod.java:139:in `call'
    from DefaultMethod.java:170:in `call'
    from CachingCallSite.java:306:in `cacheAndCall'
    from CachingCallSite.java:136:in `call'
    from VCallNode.java:88:in `interpret'
    from NewlineNode.java:105:in `interpret'
    from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
    from ASTInterpreter.java:74:in `INTERPRET_METHOD'
    from InterpretedMethod.java:204:in `call'
    from DefaultMethod.java:194:in `call'
    from CachingCallSite.java:336:in `cacheAndCall'
    from CachingCallSite.java:179:in `callBlock'
    from CachingCallSite.java:183:in `call'
    from RubyClass.java:855:in `newInstance'
    from RubyClass$INVOKER$i$newInstance.gen:-1:in `call'
    from JavaMethod.java:294:in `call'
    from CachingCallSite.java:326:in `cacheAndCall'
    from CachingCallSite.java:170:in `call'
    from CallOneArgNode.java:57:in `interpret'
    from InstAsgnNode.java:95:in `interpret'
    from NewlineNode.java:105:in `interpret'
    from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
    from ASTInterpreter.java:74:in `INTERPRET_METHOD'
    from InterpretedMethod.java:204:in `call'
    from DefaultMethod.java:194:in `call'
    from CachingCallSite.java:336:in `cacheAndCall'
    from CachingCallSite.java:179:in `callBlock'
    from CachingCallSite.java:183:in `call'
    from RubyClass.java:855:in `newInstance'
    from RubyClass$INVOKER$i$newInstance.gen:-1:in `call'
    from JavaMethod.java:294:in `call'
    from CachingCallSite.java:326:in `cacheAndCall'
    from CachingCallSite.java:170:in `call'
    from lib/main.rb:37:in `chained_0_rescue_1$RUBY$SYNTHETIC__file__'
    from lib/main.rb:34:in `__file__'
    from lib/main.rb:-1:in `load'
    from Ruby.java:807:in `runScript'
    from Ruby.java:800:in `runScript'
    from Ruby.java:669:in `runNormally'
    from Ruby.java:518:in `runFromMain'
    from Main.java:390:in `doRunFromMain'
    from Main.java:279:in `internalRun'
    from Main.java:221:in `run'
    from Main.java:201:in `main'
```

P.S.:

ruby version:

- jruby 1.7.4 (1.9.3p392) 2013-05-16 2390d3b on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.6.0_65-

java version:

- java version "1.6.0_65"
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
- Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)

Comment: can you share you main.rb at least? It's not clear what kind of server are you trying to start. Looks like there's a `require` missing there.

Comment: are you requiring the net/http/server? `require 'net/http/server'`

Comment: require 'net/http/server' - require line exist in main.rb file.

Comment: is 'net/http/server' a gem or is already included in ruby/jruby? How can I install or require it?

Comment: CommPortIdentifier.java:354:in `open': gnu.io.PortInUseException: Unknown Application
    from NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2:in `invoke0'
    from NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39:in `invoke'

Comment: it's actually a gem. `gem install net-http-server` from the cmd. If you are running it with bundler `gem 'net-http-server'` on the *Gemfile* and `bundle install` form cmd.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43776/discussion-between-robertodecurnex-and-bmalets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If cause of error:

```
CommPortIdentifier.java:354:in `open': gnu.io.PortInUseException: Unknown Application
```

just create and chmod /var/lock folder :)

```
mkdir /var/lock
chmod go+rwx /var/lock
```